# comparing user input arrays & objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to compare user input with set usernames and passwords. For now this is what I came up with:

```
var sys = {
    users: [
        {user: 'user1',  pass: 'qwerty'},
        {user: 'Ragnar',  pass: 'lothbrok'},
        {user: 'guest',  pass: 'guest'}
    ],
    valid: function(){
        var userInp = document.getElementById("userInp").value;
        // var pwInp = document.getElementById("pwInp").value;
        var check = false;
        for (var i=0; i < sys.users.length; i++ ){
            if (userInp == sys.users.user /*&& apwInp == 'sys.users{pass}'*/) {
              alert ("logged in")
            } else {
               alert ("no match")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I need to do it in this specific way and I can't figure it out.

Comment: So it's valid if a userinput matches a user - password combination?

Comment: yup. cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to have some clarity, have your username-password combination as a separate object and use the authentication in a different block of code.

```
    //username-password objects
    var sys = {
    users: [
        {user: 'user1',  pass: 'qwerty'},
        {user: 'Ragnar',  pass: 'lothbrok'},
        {user: 'guest',  pass: 'guest'}
    ]}

    //take your inputs and store them in a variable
    var username = document.getElementById("userInp").value;
    var password= document.getElementById("passInp").value;
    var count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i< sys.users.length; i++)
    {
        if(sys.users[i].user == username && sys.users[i].pass == password)
            count++;
    }

    if(count>0)
        alert("correct credentials");
    else
        alert("incorrect credentials");
```

You have pretty much in your code already, hope this clears out the rest.

Comment: This code will always alert `"incorrect"` (several times), even for valid logins.

Comment: @melpomene thanks to point it out. Fixed it. Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: Now it's completely broken.

Comment: @melpomene can you test it out before down-voting?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5x4p1u32/ It thinks `guest` / `guest` is invalid. How exactly did you "test" this?

Comment: @ ankit2012vit  thanks it is working now only issue is that its giving me 2 errors before giving out the correct log in for the last user

Comment: @ melpomene  you need to remove the break,it gives out 2 incorrects before "logging in" though

Comment: @melpomene yup i agree its not perfect yet but it is working on a basic level just need to figure out how to stop it from displaying the two incorrects

Comment: @ankit2012vit  based on your code i did this  valid: function(){
            
                var same = false;
                for(i = 0; i< sys.users.length; i++){
                    if(username == sys.users[i].user && password == sys.users[i].pass){
                        same = true;
                        }
                      } 
                     if (same == true){   
                        alert("correct");
                     } else{
                        alert("incorrect");
                     }
                
            }
            
        }

Comment: @jester3k please check this edited one out, it will work now
Basically, the action (notify about correct or incorrect) should not be in a loop because then it will happen 3 times, so i moved it out of the loop

Comment: This is better. Technically you don't need a `count` variable: You can just use a boolean `check` variable (that you set to `true` when a match is found), as in jester3k's initial code.

Comment: @melpomene duly noted :)

Comment: @melpomene thanks for the help guys! Very new to this but your explanations helped me understand it alot better!

Answer (score 0):

Use Array::some

```js
var sys = {
    users: [
        {
            user: 'user1',
            pass: 'qwerty'
        },
        {
            user: 'Ragnar',
            pass: 'lothbrok'
        },
        {
            user: 'guest',
            pass: 'guest'
        }
    ],
    valid: function () {
        let username = "Ragnar";
        let password = "lothbrok";
        return sys.users.some(u => u.user === username && u.pass === password);
    }
}

console.log(sys.valid())
```